# How to calculate the required torque or HP of single phase induction motor to carry a massive object?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, torque, electric-machine

I need to know the power of a motor in Hp required to move a vehicle of about 300 Kg. The vehicle is equipped with gear assembly and required to run at 20 to 25 Km/h. The electric motor that is i used in vehicle is single phase induction motor( 1440 rpm , 50HZ , 220V, IHP) . I want to to know how much HP of the motor will be required to carry a almost 400Kg kg with a person . ( 300kg of vehicle and 100 kg for two persons)

How can we calculate the required torque to move a massive object by means of gear assembly ?

Comment: You need to select small persons if two persons should not weigh more than 100 kg.

Comment: Thanks @ Uwe for your suggestion . a good answer . but not useful for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculate separately the powers you need for

- acceleration (simple Newtonian physics)
- hill climbing (ditto, once you decide what speed you want up what gradient),
- rolling resistance (you'll need to research that, for the ground surfaces you're crossing. It depends on speed, ground surface, type of tyre, wheel size etc, you'll find plenty of info online to get you started)
- Air resistance (again, some research needed, but you can estimate a Cd  and you know the frontal area from the bodywork design. Again there's plenty of info online)
- Losses in the gear mechanism

Add these together and you have a minimum figure for the required power, you probably want to add 10% to 50% as a safety margin. (As you probably don't need full acceleration uphill, exercise judgment whetehr to add both of these numbers, or the larger of the two).

Torque (Nm) is simply power(W) / rotational speed (radians/second).
Torque at the motor for a given velocity obviously depends on wheel size and gearing.

Comment: +1. I'd like to add a single phase induction motor is the worst choice for a vehicle as its M/n characteristic is not matching the one needed for vehicle drives. A series wired DC motor (as found in a simple 230V pistol drill) is much better suited. Lots of momentum at stillstand, great acceleration.

Comment: "lots of momentum at stillstand" oO  by definition momentum would be zero irrespective of machine topology

Comment: unfortunately , i only have sigle phase induction motor. so i decided to use this motor. i know this motor is not suitable for vehicle.

Comment: in future , i will select another motor

Comment: Dear @Brian , is there any method or formula to calculate the power of motor. ?

Comment: @Fame313 - Two ways. First, electrical power is voltage times current. Mechanical power is shaft rotation speed times shaft torque. For good motor design (which is pretty much a given these days), and a motor being operated near its intended speed and torque, mechanical power will be a few per cent less than electrical power.